# Error installing ScrAPI gem: ffi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi

I am having issues installing the ScrAPI gem:

> ERROR:  Error installing scrapi:
>      ffi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

I am running RVM and if I do ruby -v I get:

> ruby -v
>   ruby 1.9.2p110 (2010-12-20 revision 30269) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you did

```
$ sudo gem install scrapi

sudo ruby -v
```

Unless you followed Wayne's sudo RVM install I'm guessing root uses a different ruby.